# Follow someone down street or down to street

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in meaning between these examples ?

1-Don't follow women ***down dark alleys*** after dark.

2-Don't follow women ***down to dark alleys*** after dark.

3-Don't follow women ***to dark alleys*** after dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1 is the natural phrasing.

Example 2 and 3, the meaning has changed. The scope of advice applies only until reaching a dark alley. Once you've gone to the dark alley and are inside it then you're beyond the context. Could be rephrased as "don't follow women *to* dark alleys - but once you get there and are in the dark alley it's ok to follow them".

In example 2, the "down" would be adding texture/emphasis and would occur only in spoken English.

Comment: What is the meaning of the "to" in  the sentence 2, isn't it like the sentence 3 ? I think that "to" is still indicate that follow them until you reach a dark alley.

Comment: yes! I got that wrong [fixed]

Comment: Thanks :) Could you explain the sentence 1 in more detail ? Is it mean that don't follow them along dark alleys or ıs there  a different meaning in that sentence ?

Comment: That's exactly the meaning. The trailing "after dark" is probably extra.